# Rails: Model methods issue with saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model

I have a `text_area` named `answer_choices` in my form that's used for inputting answers (separated by a line break):

```
Some answer
Another answer
Yet another
```

So when a users submits the form, I parse `answer_choices` out into individual answers for input into the database using `answer_choices.split(/\r\n/)`

Then, when they edit the form, I reassemble those individual answers using this method:

I have the following method in my `Question` model:

```
def answer_choices
  string = ''

  answers.each do |answer|
    string += "#{answer.text.to_s}\n"
  end

  string.strip
end
```

That lets me just do `<%= f.text_area :answer_choices %>` in my view and I get the answers separated by line breaks. Great.

The problem is that when I submit the form again (to update the records), that little `answer_choices.split(/\r\n/)` bit seems to be calling that custom method instead of taking any new data from the form field and thus just re-adds the same data from before.

So how can I have my custom method for the form output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid calling your custom method you should use the attributes hash:

```
self.attributes['answer_choices'].split(/\r\n/)
```

Comment: `self.attributes['answer_choices']` is empty. I have `attr_accessor :answer_choices` set in the model, but `self.inspect` doesn't show `answer_choices` anywhere.